# Display text next to the checkbox in a new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to switch the text right of this checkbox to a new row, without changing the structure of html, is there a CSS solution perhaps or maybe with JS..? Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6svxtdsk/

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
    <input required="required" class="check" id="check" type="checkbox" name="name" value="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab magni, exercitationem minus aliquid sunt animi et odit, obcaecati consequatur distinctio. Alias consequuntur odio, soluta at reprehenderit nesciunt repudiandae fugit quae. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, consequuntur, modi! Esse at nesciunt officia voluptate ipsam sapiente provident enim magni, temporibus recusandae inventore doloremque rem quaerat soluta aut, nihil.
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `display: block` to the CSS of the checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A display:block on the input would do the trick if I understand you correctly.

```css
.checkbox label input{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
    <input required="required" class="check" id="check" type="checkbox" name="name" value="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab magni, exercitationem minus aliquid sunt animi et odit, obcaecati consequatur distinctio. Alias consequuntur odio, soluta at reprehenderit nesciunt repudiandae fugit quae. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, consequuntur, modi! Esse at nesciunt officia voluptate ipsam sapiente provident enim magni, temporibus recusandae inventore doloremque rem quaerat soluta aut, nihil.
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this css:

```
.checkbox label input {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.checkbox label input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
    <input required="required" class="check" id="check" type="checkbox" name="name" value="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab magni, exercitationem minus aliquid sunt animi et odit, obcaecati consequatur distinctio. Alias consequuntur odio, soluta at reprehenderit nesciunt repudiandae fugit quae. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, consequuntur, modi! Esse at nesciunt officia voluptate ipsam sapiente provident enim magni, temporibus recusandae inventore doloremque rem quaerat soluta aut, nihil.
  </label>
</div>
```